# A Strange Contacts

Tags: applications, security, contacts, gmail

I found a strange contact with a short strange number on my android device.

The contact name is "Siiii" and the number is a combination of just 10 numbers. Is this a spam? Or a hacking issue? I hope anyone could help me with that.

Thanks

Comment: "Or a hacking issue?"... No, that is as likely as being struck by lightning while being bitten by a shark... It's possible, but extremely unlikely. In your contacts, it should show a line towards the bottom saying "Added May 1, 2023 (name@email.com)" or similar that could give you a clue (at least Pixel's do) telling you the date and account that added it if done from the phone, if not, it was added by syncing from your Google or similar account.